# Calling a function and not moving on until complete?

Tags: javascript

I call two functions in my js which get data via ajax:

```
getNumContentTotal(ctx);
getContentAll(ctx);
```

getNumContentTotal(ctx) sets a var that is required by getContentAll(ctx);

Is there a way of not executing the second function until my var is set?

Comment: You need to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: Default behaviour is that `getContentAll()` will be executed _after_ `getNumContentTotal()` has finished, including setting any variables.

Comment: Marcell Fülöp, not if I'm waiting for an ajax return.

Comment: Why not just call `getContentAll(ctx);` when ajax of `getNumContentTotal(ctx);` is done(`.done()` function of ajax)?

Comment: What JS library are you using? jQuery?

Comment: Have a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (which I'm assuming you are) then return the object that ajax call returns in your `getNumContentTotal()` and `getContentAll()` methods. jQuery returns a promise like object allowing you to manage callbacks in a serialized way:

**EDIT**: A better article on jQuery's promises: [Understanding JQuery.Deferred and Promise](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/).

```
function getNumContentTotal(ctx) {
  return $.ajax(...);
}

function getContentAll(ctx) {
  return $.ajax(...);
}

var promise = getNumContentTotal(ctx);
promise.pipe(function(data) {
  // do something with data
  return getContentAll(ctx);
}).done(function(data) {
  // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
function getNumContentTotal(ctx)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        getContentAll(data);
    });

}

function getContentAll(ctx)
{
   //other function
}
```

So you only call the next function when the first function has been loaded. This way the variable you will give to the next function is *always* filled.